# add class and remove from element to anther siblings - javascript tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to click on button , transfer class name that have the color from the active element to next one.

this not real task i just learn but i blocked

```js
var el = document.getElementById('one');
var boxDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('.box');
var btnCh = document.getElementById('changeColor');

btnCh.onclick = function() {
  if (boxDiv.classList.contains('green')) {
    boxDiv.nextSiblings.classList.add('green');
    boxDiv.previousSiblings.classList.add('green');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="box green" id="one"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="box "><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="box"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <button id="changeColor">add class</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/hesham-farag/pen/MZLxeM

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to click on one of the boxes, transfer the color from the active element to the one you clicked?

Comment: Check your console. You'll have several errors there.

Comment: Remove the dot from .box and if you are targeting classes your boxDiv becomes an object array, so as of now you might get undefined errors in your console since you haven't specified an index for your boxDiv

Comment: i want to click on button , transfer class name that have the color from the active element to next one.

Comment: @JulianEspinosa i delete dot but still not work with me , what did you mean make object of arry , sorry i still learning so i confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create some logic here. If you want to have one colored box from list of all, you have to remember your previous main box. So, you'll write next instructions:

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="box main"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="box green" id="one" ><span>2</span>   </div>
</div>
<button>Change main box</button>
```

js:

```
let boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));
let button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
let mainBoxIndex = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  boxes[mainBoxIndex].classList.remove('main');
  mainBoxIndex = (mainBoxIndex + 1 < boxes.length) ? mainBoxIndex + 1 : 0;
  boxes[mainBoxIndex].classList.add('main');
});
```

Get closer look you can here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXJyqQ
Hope it'll help you a bit.

Comment: i just if explain more about this block of code ? (mainBoxIndex + 1 < boxes.length) ? mainBoxIndex + 1 : 0;

Comment: Read more about ternary operator here: https://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html
It's one of view of "If else" statement. If index of current image + 1 Lower then maximum of boxes, than we increment it by one, in other case we set it to 0 (that means the first block main again).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code (always check the console for errors).

Firstly, understand the difference between a node and a nodeset. Functions like `getElementsByClassName` return a node*set*, which is an array-like collection of nodes. You therefore cannot run node methods on them as you are, i.e. this will cause an error:

```
boxDiv.nextSiblings(... //boxDiv is not a node; it's a nodeset
```

Therefore, you need to loop over the nodeset and deal with each element in turn.

Next, `nextSiblings` and `previousSiblings` are not valid methods; they should be in the singular, not plural.

Next, you're *assuming* there's a next and previous sibling. This will error on the first and last `.box` div for obvious reasons.

Also, while we're here:

- it's generally better to avoid "level 0" DOM events e.g. `.onclick` and instead use `addEventListener()`. There are several reasons for this that are beyond the scope of this answer.
- these days unless you need to support old browsers it's better to use `let` than `var`

Let's pull it all together

```
let
parent = document.querySelector('#row'),
boxDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.box'),
btnCh = document.querySelector('#changeColor')
;

btnCh.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    boxDiv.forEach(el => {
        if (el.classList.contains('green')) {
            if (el.nextSibling) el.nextSibling.classList.add('green');
            if (el.previousSibling) el.previousSibling.classList.add('green');
        }
    });
}, false);
```